# right expression for "get money out from hopper"

Tags: word-choice, expressions

There is a game machine with a coin hopper.
When the player wins, the hopper pays some coins.

The technician is able to add or remove coins from the hopper by hand.

What is the right way to describe this action from the technician? If I search on the web, I find different ways to describe it. But I am not able to get the correct form:

- remove money from hopper
- take out money from hopper
- pull out money from hopper
- withdraw money from hopper

"remove" is normally used to install or remove devices, not coins, right?
"take out" seems more an expression for objects and not money.
"pull out" is like take out, not referred to money.
"withdraw" means to get back some money if you received too much.

So, what is the right way to say: "there was 104 coins in the hopper, the technician .... 4 coins"?

Comment: *What is the right way to describe this action from the technician?* The correct way is **any of the ways that you list**. There is no single *correct* way. That said, "pull out" and "withdraw" have more specialised meanings and are more specific as to the action and are thus not as idiomatic.

Answer (score 1):

Get.. from, Take.. out.  Maybe: Grab, Empty.

“Get the money from the hopper.”

“He got the money from the hopper.”

Or if only getting some of it: “Get money from the hopper.”

———

To be only slightly colorful: “Grab some money from the hopper for your pizza.”

———

“He took the money out of the hopper.”

“Step 2: Take the money out of the hopper.”

“Then he took the money from the hopper.” Take.. from, also works, sometimes.

———

Less so:
“He emptied the money out of the hopper.”

Formal/technical:

“Step two: Empty the money from the hopper.” “Remove the money from the hopper.”

I can imagine another native speaker saying any of those, but not anything you wrote, except for take out.